# Python Regular Expression to find all combinations of a Letter Number Letter Designation

Tags: python, regex, search, replace, python-2.6

I need to implement a Python regular expression to search for a all occurrences `A1a` or `A_1_a` or `A-1-a` or `_A_1_a_` or `_A1a`, where:

- `A` can be **A to Z**.
- `1` can be **1 to 9**.
- `a` can be **a to z**.

Where there are only three characters letter number letter, separated by Underscores, Dashes or nothing. The case in the search string needs to be matched exactly.

The main problem I am having is that sometimes these three letter combinations are connected to other text by dashes and underscores.  Also creating the same regular expression to search for `A1a`, `A-1-a` and `A_1_a`.

Also I forgot to mention this is an XML file.

Thanks this found every occurrence of what I was looking for with a slight modification [-]?[A][-]?[1][-]?[a][-]?, but I need to have these be variables something like

```
    [-]?[var_A][-]?[var_3][-]?[Var_a][-]?
```

would that be done like this

```
    regex = r"[-]?[%s][-]?[%s][-]?[%s][-]?" 
    print re.findall(regex,var_A,var_Num,Var_a)
```

Or more like:

```
    regex = ''.join(['r','\"','[-]?[',Var_X,'][-]?[',Var_Num,'][-]?[',Var_x,'][-]?','\"'‌​])
    print regex 
    for sstr in searchstrs: 
            matches = re.findall(regex, sstr, re.I)
```

But this isn't working

Sample Lines of the File:
Before Running Script

```
<t:ION t:SA="BoolObj" t:H="2098947" t:P="2098944" t:N="AN7 Result" t:CI="Boolean_Register" t:L="A_3_a  Fdr2" t:VS="true">
<t:ION t:SA="RegisterObj" t:H="20971785" t:P="20971776" t:N="ART1 Result 1" t:CI="NumericVariable_Register" t:L="A3a1 Status" t:VS="1">
<t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2100736" t:P="2097152" t:N="AND/OR 14" t:CI="AndOr_Module" t:L="A_3_a**_2 Energized from Norm" t:S="0" t:SC="5">
```

After Running Script
What I am getting:  (It's deleting the entire line and leaving only what is below)

- B_1_c
- B1c1
- B_1_c_2

What I Want to get:

```
<t:ION t:SA="BoolObj" t:H="2098947" t:P="2098944" t:N="AN7 Result" t:CI="Boolean_Register" t:L="B_1_c  Fdr2" t:VS="true">
<t:ION t:SA="RegisterObj" t:H="20971785" t:P="20971776" t:N="ART1 Result 1" t:CI="NumericVariable_Register" t:L="B1c1 Status" t:VS="1">
<t:ION t:SA="ModuleObj" t:H="2100736" t:P="2097152" t:N="AND/OR 14" t:CI="AndOr_Module" t:L="B_1_c_2 Energized from Norm" t:S="0" t:SC="5">

import re
import os

search_file_name = 'Alarms Test.fwn'
pattern = 'A3a'
fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(search_file_name)
newfilename = fileName + '_' + pattern + fileExtension
outfile = open(newfilename, 'wb')


def find_ext(text):
    matches = re.findall(r'([_-]?[A{1}][_-]?[3{1}][_-]?[a{1}][_-]?)', text)
    records = [m.replace('3', '1').replace('A', 'B').replace('a', 'c') for m in matches]
    if matches:
        outfile.writelines(records)
        return 1
    else:
        outfile.writelines(text)
        return 0


def main():
    success = 0
    count = 0
    with open(search_file_name, 'rb') as searchfile:
        try:
            searchstrs = searchfile.readlines()
            for s in searchstrs:
                success = find_ext(s)
                count = count + success
        finally:
            searchfile.close()

    print count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What should `A1A1A` return?  IOW, what about potential overlaps?

Comment: Do you want to match the underscore/dash at the beginning? In other words, should the match for `_A_1_a_` be `_A_1_a_` or `A_1_a`?

Comment: Yes there could be XMDC_A1a or XMDC-A1a or XMDC_A1-a XMDC_A_1_a_Current all in the same file.

Comment: @rtsnhth Did one of these solutions work for you? If so please accept and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the following to find your matches.

```
matches = re.findall(r'([_-]?[a-z][_-]?[1-9][_-]?[a-z][_-]?)', s, re.I)
```

See [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bK6kO8)

If your are looking to find the matches then strip all of the `-`, `_` characters, you could do..

```
import re

s = '''
A1a _A_1 A_ A_1_a A-1-a _A_1_a_ _A1a _A-1-A_ a1_a  A-_-5-a
_A-_-5-A a1_-1 XMDC_A1a or XMDC-A1a or XMDC_A1-a XMDC_A_1_a_ _A-1-A_
'''

def find_this(text):
    matches = re.findall(r'([_-]?[a-z][_-]?[1-9][_-]?[a-z][_-]?)', text, re.I)
    records = [m.replace('-', '').replace('_', '') for m in matches]
    print records

find_this(s)
```

Output

```
['A1a', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'A1A', 'a1a', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'A1A']
```

See [working demo](https://eval.in/55499)

Answer (score 1):

To quickly get the `A1a`s out without the punctuation, and not having to reconstruct the string from captured parts...

```
t = '''A1a _B_2_z_ 
A_1_a 
A-1-a 
_A_1_a_ 
_C1c '''

re.findall("[A-Z][0-9][a-z]",t.replace("-","").replace("_",""))
```

Output:

```
['A1a', 'B2z', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'C1c']
```

(But if you *don't* want to capture from `FILE.TXT-2b`, then you would have to be careful about most of these solutions...)

Answer (score 0):

If the string can be separated by multiple underscores or dashes (e.g. `A__1a`):

```
[_-]*[A-Z][_-]*[1-9][_-]*[a-z]
```

If there can only be one or zero underscores or dashes:

```
[_-]?[A-Z][_-]?[1-9][_-]?[a-z]
```

Comment: afaik this would accept illegal matches for example `A-_-5-a`

Comment: The poster said "Underscores, dashes, or nothing."

Comment: afaik he meant one per seperator but your right ... thats a believable statement and I could be wrong so +1

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = r"[A-Z][-_]?[1-9][-_]?[a-z]"
print re.findall(regex,some_string_variable)
```

should work

to just capture the parts your interested in wrap them in parens

```
regex = r"([A-Z])[-_]?([1-9])[-_]?([a-z])"
print re.findall(regex,some_string_variable)
```

if the underscores or dashes or lack thereof **must** match or it will return bad results you would need a statemachine whereas regex is stateless

Comment: Don't forget the possible underscore at the front

Comment: doesnt matter with findall (unless he actually wants to capture that as well... but it sounds like all he really cares about are the 3 characters

Comment: Just as an exercise, how would you use groupings to capture just the 3 desired characters, thus normalizing the return data?

Comment: what about it mridule? it would be captured fine. @CDSpace .. just put parens around each place of interest : `([A-Z])[-_]?([1-9])[-_]?([a-z])`

Comment: ahh you may be right ... it should still find all matches and not return any false matches

Comment: Thanks this found every occurrence of what I was looking for with a slight modification [_-]?[A][_-]?[1][_-]?[a][_-]?, but I need to have these be variables something like [_-]?[var_A][_-]?[var_3][_-]?[Var_a][_-]? would that be done like this regex = r"[_-]?[%s][_-]?[%s][_-]?[%s][_-]?"  print re.findall(regex,var_A,var_Num,Var_a)

Comment: Or more like:regex = ''.join(['r','\"','[_-]?[',Var_X,'][_-]?[',Var_Num,'][_-]?[',Var_x,'][_-]?','\"'])
                print regex
                for sstr in searchstrs:
                    matches = re.findall(regex, sstr, re.I)